# Is a Pokémon's weight and height relevant?

Tags: pokemon-go

Does a Pokémon's weight and height influence their CP?

Or are the differences between Pokémon weight/height purely cosmetic, i.e. "just for fun"?

Comment: The game is still relatively new and no correlation between CP and height/weight exists yet. However, that doesn't mean it's not there. Niantic doesn't like adding irrelevant things to their games. Although, many beta testers reported seeing no correlation between pokemon of differing statistics, except for the XL Magikarp badge.

Comment: Its not about the outside, its about the insides.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion, this conversation has moved to [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42187/discussion-between-timelord64-and-kaz-wolfe)

Comment: I've already unchecked, sorry. It seems to be random then, or at least uncorrelated with wight and height parameters.

Comment: [Relevant Meta about possible duplication](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11802/are-these-two-duplicate-questions-and-if-so-how-should-they-be-handled)

Comment: @Timelord64 Not only that, but THIS question was asked sooner ... how can an early question be a duplicate of later question ....

Comment: @ИвоНедев, long story, Dragonrage mentions a meta, look at my answer, but TLDR, we gosh darn doofed

Comment: @ИвоНедев See this meta: [On ending Chronological Oppression with respect to the matter of Question Duplication](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/8188/28182)

Answer (score 14):

**Update**: It appears that the conclusion below is false, and as of now we are unsure of the correlation between Weight/Height and any other of the Pokémon's stats. I have seen several counter-examples to the trend I observed, both from personal experience and from other people and so I am no longer confident that there is a relationship. Once more information, incorporating moveset and other variables (such as - "was it caught at this CP level or did you raise it to this CP level?"), comes to light, hopefully we will have a more definitive explanation for the variability of HP vs CP.

---

The tests I conducted showed that **yes**, weight (and possibly height) are relevant to a Pokémon's stats. From what I saw, for two Pokémon of the **same CP**, the one with **higher weight** will have **higher HP**. This means that it is more important to hold on to Heavier (XL) Pokémon and place less emphasis on raising XS Pokémon. I did not focus on height when I pulled my sample together, but there is no clear trend across the two examples I used, its effects will need to be looked into further.

The two separate cases I used to come to this conclusion are as follows-

### First Case:

I captured two Pidgeys of the same CP level (93) in a very short time. Comparing their weights, I found that one had higher HP, and realized that this was positively correlated with weight. Interestingly, in this case the Pidgey with the larger height value was the one with less HP, which I thought may thought might indicate a negative correlation, but this was not consistent with the next case.

[image]
[image]

### Second Case:

I had one sparrow of CP level 77 and another at a lower CP level, but with an (XL) tag for it's weight. I upgraded the lower one to CP 75, and discovered that the (XL) Pokémon had more health than its smaller cousin (who was two CP levels higher). This certainly offers more support in favor of weight factoring into a Pokémon's HP. Interestingly in this example the height increased along with the HP/weight, arguing against a negative correlation.

[image]
[image]

The amounts shown for HP differences may seem small, but keep in mind that this is at very low CP levels, so I expect the effect to be more noticeable at higher levels.

Obviously this is only two cases, so drawing conclusions based off of such a small sample size isn't ideal, and I will try to find more examples that can help shed light on this relationship. If anyone has any contradictory examples please post them, as it would definitely help clear this up.

Edit: I'll post the additional cases tomorrow, but I have found four more examples where a higher weight Pokémon of equal or lesser CP has a higher HP than its smaller cousin.

Comment: I have 2 venonat with 121 cp and the XL actually has less health

Comment: I posted a counter argument answer.

Comment: Perhaps the move sets are different? That could affect the CP since CP should be related to health as well.

Comment: The first part of this question reads "below is incorrect". If it is incorrect, delete it.

Comment: this is because of the pokemon's IV, NOT weight.

Answer (score 10):

Counter argument to turner:

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the higher weight, height, and CP has fewer hitpoints.

Comment: I've unchecked the "correct answer" flag from the turner's thanks to this last answer and the one of @Jessica Thompson.

Comment: Ah, just ran into a pair like this myself, back to the drawing board!

Comment: This could just be random happenstance, though. Is there any *definitive* evidence that this CP thing is not just a coincidence? I've experienced quite a few XS Pokemon having more CP, which seems odd if this is the case.

Comment: @KazWolfe nothing but theories at this time. But we are working on it

Comment: Though they're both within the same weight class. It's still possible that an XL will always have a higher HP than an XS.

Comment: @Patrick good point, but not true. I have a counter to that if I can find it again

Comment: Maybe, the IV has better/worse "stamina" for each, but, the HP would be a combination of stamina, weight, height?

Answer (score 2):

Since Niantic's official announcement that a buddy system will be included in the next version, see [here](http://pokemongo.nianticlabs.com/en/post/buddy/), and the subsequent code-data-mining, see [here](http://pokemongohub.net/pokemon-buddy-system-data-mined/), we now have another idea for the reason of including the Pokémons' sizes: it might be the actual size your buddy Pokémon will have walking next to you (i.e. an XS Pikachu will appear smaller than an XL Pikachu).

Although, according to the code analysis, your buddy's size might only alternate between the following values:

```
BUDDY_MEDIUM = 0;
BUDDY_SHOULDER = 1;
BUDDY_BIG = 2;
BUDDY_FLYING = 3;
```

Maybe those are only the base stats to which the Pokémon's actual size is added. We'll find out soon.

Comment: it looks like this is more of how to display the "buddy" in the profile page, sitting on your shoulder, flying by you, standing behind you, etc

Answer (score 1):

i tried to search out the answer i found some answers related to this but i don't got the perfect one.here's all i got,

**the most preferred one** :

the cp and the hp is directly  proportional to each other mean if cp is higher than your hp will be higher and as of the weight it has .04% effect on hp and .03% effect on cp. for the height is has some great effect relative to weight(check the image).for **proof** [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t28oq/stats_data_links_found_between_cp_and_hp_and_also/). and **charts and other info** [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kODqI.jpg).

NOTE : this conclusion is based on data not from the official(i.e, pokemon go developers etc.)

for **second one** that also convinced me here,

```
    the weight is prefered for attack power mean higher the weight more powerful attack is.

    as of the height there is no mention to it

    NOTE : this data is based on the xl,xs,normal for weight and height
```

proof [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4skhzw/pok%C3%A9mon_weight_and_height_explained/)

Answer (score -1):

Possibly a difference in HP. I had 2 of the same pokemon the had significantly different weight and the same CP with a difference of 1HP.

Comment: could you be more specific?