# I've got an "XS" Pokémon. Is it special?

Tags: pokemon-go

Whilst checking my Pokémon, I saw one Pidgey with very small CP value in comparison to his brethren. I noticed his weight is smaller, and he has an "XS" mark (see the screenshot).

Is this special? Can I do something with it? Is it more valuable?

[image: screenshot of an "XS" Pidgey]

Comment: XS = eXtra Small,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is a Pokémon's weight and height relevant?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/is-a-pok%c3%a9mons-weight-and-height-relevant)

Comment: [Relevant Meta about possible duplication](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/11802/are-these-two-duplicate-questions-and-if-so-how-should-they-be-handled)

Comment: rolling back as per meta

Comment: I think we need some more official information in order to decide if normal, XS or XL are to be prefered. I doubt tokens are the only things affected by this.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There is nothing particularly special about an extra small pokémon. Typically, smaller pokémon appear to start with lower CP values, but that is about it.

That said, there may be further medals that relate to the weight of a pokémon. For example, there is the *Youngster* medal.

[image]

Comment: I've not experienced XS Pokemon having higher or lower starting CPs than others. In fact, some XS Pokemon have had CPs that far surpassed their XL counterparts.

Comment: I love how their token replacement code isn't replacing tokens.

Comment: @Ellesedil, I have absolutely no idea what your talking about

Comment: @Timelord64 he means the curly brackets here: https://0ws.pw/zmeo.png

Comment: Does Machop perchance have Low Kick available as a special? It would likely influence the damage Low Kick (and Grass Knot/Heavy Slam etc) do.

Answer (score 21):

A Pokémon with an **XS** tag, for either weight or height, is a sign that this Pokémon has lower than average values for those stats. As was explored in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/is-a-pok%C3%A9mons-weight-and-height-relevant), it appears that higher weight leads to higher health for two Pokémon of the same CP value. From this, one can conclude that a Pokémon with **XL** tags for height and weight is generally going to be a better choice than the same Pokémon with **XS** tags.

I've read in a few places that these tags also influence your Pokémon's moveset, although I haven't seen any evidence to back this up.

Comment: that's not true

Comment: I have noticed my XS vaporeon attack and dodge way faster than the XL one that is in the same CP range. The XL having better HP/stamina makes sense. You say the XL would be better, but that depends on which you value more, higher HP or the quicker attack and dodge.

Answer (score 8):

Actually, the size has a lot to do with the Pokémon's stats in the game. I leveled up two Pidgeys until they were both at the same point on the CP meter. One was an XL and the other regular. The XL's CP was 79, while the other's was at 73. So imagine the margin between an XL and XS Pokémon. It could be a very big CP difference.

And to the above theory that an XL Pokémon requires more stardust and candy - it's simply not true. I have an XL and regular Venonat at the same spot on the CP meter and they both take 400 stardust and one candy to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

Smaller pokemons tend to have faster attack speeds than normal ones.

Comment: Do you have a source or some proof for this?

Comment: Personal experience. Had 2 gravelers, same attacks, roughly same cp. The heavy one was attacking like 1 per second, the lighter one was attacking like 3 per second. There are also reddit posts in silph road where people also posted this experience. I also experienced it with electabuzz too.

Comment: Would like to see some harder evidence of this, but sounds plausible from what I see from my experience too. My XS Vaporeon attacks super fast.

Comment: Attack speed is only affected by the move itself and the player input e.g. if the player taps once every 3 sec, the move will be used less often. It has nothing to do with the Pokemon size

Answer (score -3):

If it is extra large it takes more stardust to power it up. For example: a normal size Weedle costs 200 + 1 candy, whereas my XL one takes 400 Stardust and 1 candy.

I'm still working on gym tests between the two after paying to get them to match their CPs together and testing HP difference now

Comment: Do you have a source for this? If their CPs are not equal how do you know that is not affecting how much stardust it costs?

Comment: CP does, in fact, alter required stardust. Higher CP requires more

Answer (score -3):

I have two **Pidgeotto** and one is **XS** with more **CP** and health than the **XL** one. And to power it up my **XS** needs more stardust than my **XL**... YET, my **XS** **Seaking** does not need more stardust than my regular **Seaking**.... Same with all of my **rattata**... In *conclusion* I THINK (dont get me wrong) that it all depends on the **CP** of THAT kind of pokemon, maybe from this range to that rage needs this much stardust, ect. But ***varying*** of the kind of Pokemon.

Comment: This seems like it would be far more helpful as a comment.