# Evolving XL pokemon became XS

Tags: pokemon-go

I had a pokemon which was XL at height and weight. After I evolved it, it suddenly was XS. Why did this happen? I expected these stats to stay at XL.

Comment: Possible duplicate : [I've got an “XS” or “XL” Pokémon. Is it special?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272676/ive-got-an-xs-or-xl-pok%C3%A9mon-is-it-special).

Comment: @Jouramie Questions are asking different things, so these aren't duplicates.

Answer (score 5):

It seems that size gets "re-rolled" upon evolution. I've had this happen to me, too. I think I also had an XS Pokemon become XL.

Comment: oh ok... so there will be high waste of evolving pokemons and ressources for evolving... i always cared about XL stats when evolving,..

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be bugged.

Every single evolve I have done has resulted in the Pokémon being XS in weight, and height is unaffected.

I'm level 15, and have evolved 15 pokémon. All are now XS. Some were normal, most were XL.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think their weight changes. it's how the weight is classified in the form. For example, I evolved an XL Eevee which was 8.7 kg into a XS Joltean which was also 8.7 kg.

Comment: Eevee's average weight is 6.5 kg and Jolteon's is 24.5 kg. Your Jolteon isn't XS, it's starving.