# Does pokemon size (XS/Normal/XL) influence attack power?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've noticed that for the same pokemon at the same Power Up cost, the attacks of the XS pokemon are better than that of normal or XL.

Is there official data confirming/debunking this hypothesis?

Notice, that this is a different question to the one [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272676/ive-got-an-xs-or-xl-pok%C3%A9mon-is-it-special). That question is focused on the size of the pokemon--and mentions that larger pokemon have higher health.
My question here is then, do smaller pokemon have higher attack power? If there's no health benefit, then does this mean that there's an attack bonus?

Comment: That's not what I'm asking. Please read the updated question.

Comment: The alt question was updated to simply ask "is there ANYTHING differant". If it does not mention attack power, that is because the users have not found anything relating to attack power.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.. I got a maxed out Electrabuzz and Pigeot (both are a bit over 1000cp) whereas my tiny not maxed out Vaporeons are at 1250cp and 1500cp. Vaporeons are tiny (XS). I think it us depends on the pokemon but some are obviously stronger than others.