# What is Youngster?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have the achievement "Youngster" in progress with a peculiar description:

[image]

I've definitely caught more than 1 Rattata. Just look at my candies for proof:

[image]

Am I missing something here or is this achievement broken?

Comment: it has to be between certain weight & height limits

Comment: I was wondering the same thing actually - I intentionally caught several Rattata and my progress didn't increase on this badge.

Comment: I remember the tooltip to say Rattata of a particular weight

Comment: @Insane The tool tip said so I believe. Not in a position to double check it right now ;)

Comment: It's currently bugged. No need to check since Niantic changed the description. It *used* to say something about a certain weight, but apparently it doesn't anymore. It should register fine, if you catch a qualified Rattata, though. (probably XS size)

Comment: Youngster was a name for a common type of trainer you would face in Pokémon Red / Blue / Yellow

Comment: @Spork yes exactly. "Yougster <put a name here> wants to challenge you for a battle :)

Comment: @Spork And in _Gold_ / _Silver_ / _Crystal_, Youngster Joey's Rattata was in the top percentage of Rattatas.  [By which he means IVs of 9 Atk/8 Def/8 Spd/8 Spe (and implicitly 8 HP) in gen II (very slightly above average, IVs were 0-15 in gen I/II), and 0/0/0/0/0/0 in gen IV (standard IVs for most normal trainers' pokemon).  [It was initially believed that its IVs were 30/31/29/31/26/30 in gen IV, which would mean that it really _was_ in the top percentage, but this was sadly disproven by hackers.]

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The Youngster achievement is actually awarded for catching some number of Rattata below a certain weight.

The achievement previously stated "Caught {0} Rattata weighing at most {1}". In many programming languages, `{0}` and `{1}` are just ways to substitute numbers into some text. It seems that Niantic simply messed up the description, even though it tracks correctly.

A screenshot may be found at [Timelord64's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/revisions/272678/1) to the question [I've got an “XS” Pokémon. Is it special?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/272676), reproduced here:
[image: "Youngster: Caught {0} Rattata weighing at most {1}."]

[The badge is called `BADGE_SMALL_RATTATA` in the data dump](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L74). The data dump lists its targets as `\0032\254\002`, which translates to requirements of 3, 50, and 300. There's no indication for weight, but I suspect it just requires XS Rattata.

Regarding XS Rattata specifically, I hypothesise that a Rattata is XS if it is 2 standard deviations below the mean. [The mean for Rattata is 3.5 kg, and the standard deviation is 0.4375 kg](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/077d6dea82d58b8febde54ae9729b1bf#file-game_master_v0_1-protobuf-L1506), so you should be getting it for Rattata below 2.625 kg. (The game only shows two digits for weight, so this falls between 2.62 and 2.63 kg. I hypothesise this because I have a 2.4 kg XS Rattata, and a 2.75 kg regular Rattata.)

Comment: This answer would be complete with some details as to what that weight is, maybe a screenshot of the old text? This could be heresy.

Comment: The description just says "Caught 11 Rattata" for me - no mention of weight. Are you saying it _used_ to be with the weight note, but that was removed in an update?

Comment: @TimMalone You're correct -- it used to have the `{0}` and `{1}`, but it seems to have been removed in a server-side update.

Comment: Possibly the data dump has info.

Comment: Incidentally, the name of the achievement is probably a reference to Youngster Joey: http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/youngster-joey

Comment: It appears in the most recent app update - marked "minor text fixes" - this badge's description is now "Caught x tiny Ratatta"

Comment: I have just confirm that both Weight and Height have to be XS to get a younger Rattata as for Magikarp XL

Answer (score 3):

```
Items {
  TemplateId: "BADGE_SMALL_RATTATA"
  Badge {
    BadgeType: BADGE_SMALL_RATTATA
    BadgeRanks: 4
    Targets: "\0032\254\002"
  }
}
```

Although it doesn't say so in the description anymore the badge is supposed to be awarded for catching lightweight Rattata. The name  *BADGE_SMALL_RATTATA* is pretty obvious. It's the opposite of the Magikarp badge, where you need *big* catches to get it.

Some communities confirm the text to be bugged, some say it's the badge itself, that's bugged. My recent Rattata catches showed a working badge with incorrect tool tip text.

Answer (score 0):

it say: Caught [0] Rattata weighing at most [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUH6I.jpg) 
so the rattata you catch must be light weight

[image]

Comment: Mine and seemingly everyone in the comments don't see that..

Comment: maybe is something to do with the update. i didnt update yet cause when i did i had problems so i downgrade. the thing is , must be extra small or light weight, i have the achievment done

Comment: Get a screenshot of it then before you update and add that to your answer to support it

Answer (score -1):

Tiny Rattata is any Rattata with a CP of 10 or less. As you increase your level by XP, tinny rattatas become harder to find

Comment: It's actually designated by the XS you see on size/weight. See the accepted answer. CP doesn't change whether or not it's tiny or large.

Comment: There are no <10 CPs.