# Should I keep Pokemon with high CP, Attack, or Weight?

Tags: pokemon-go

Forgive me if my Google skills are poor but putting so many words in a question didn't yield a satisfactory answer to me on the web.

I caught multiple of the same Pokemon.  I want to transfer them to get candy and free up space to catch more.  However, which one should I get rid of, high weight, high CP, or high attack?

These are the rough numbers from what I remember before I transferred them but hopefully they illustrate my question/dilemma.  The numbers aren't exact since I had already transferred them since I needed the space but is basically what I observed.

#### Pokemon A

```
CP: 294 
HP: 52 
Weight: 30.53 kg
Bug Bite (bug) 6 
Poison Fang (poison) 15
```

#### Pokemon B

```
CP 280
HP = 54
Weight 31.0
Bug bite (bug) 6
Signal Beam (bug) 35
```

#### Pokemon C

```
CP 190
HP = 46
Weight 27.9
Bug bite (bug) 6
Poison Fang (poison) 35
```

Poke A has the highest CP out of the three.  However, its attack is the weakest of the three BUT it has two different attack types (bug and poison).

Poke B is almost the same as A but it's a little heavier, the HI is slightly higher and CP is slightly lower but the attacks are higher than A, but it's only of one type (bug).

Poke C has the lowest CP, HP, and weight but just like sports, since it is behind by 100CP, it's POSSIBLE thru training and stuff that it could get up to its big brother.  Also, in addition to growth potential, it has both types of attacks and both attacks are high.

So which of the three do I keep?  Poke A b/c it has the highest CP, Poke B b/c it's close to Poke A and has better attacks and slightly better HP, or Poke C due to its potential and attack?

Comment: A, because they are venonats and things change when they evolve, the only thing you keep is the CP so that's all you should base your decision off.

Comment: @Aequitas, does this apply to all other pokemons?  To just keep the highest CP?  If so, then i'm stupid b/c I chose B several times and dumped A, although, they were close in CP so hopefully it doesn't come back to bite me in the butt.

Comment: For the final form (venomoth in this scenario) it doesn't apply, the moves are very important, I have two scythers for instance, one does 3 damage the other does 15, so obviously the 15 is way better to keep as I can just power it up to the same CP and then it will do 5x the damage as the other one.

Comment: @Aequitas, darn, so it seems like depending on the pokemon, selecting highest CP is the best strategy, while for other pokemon, it's not?  this game is way more complicated than I thought!  Is there some site/table/excel sheet showing when it's best to keep based on CP and when it's best to keep based on attacks due to what it morphs to?

Comment: I think I got a downvote.  Just wondering what was wrong with my question, like does it need more specific info, rather than rough numbers or is this common knowledge and I'm stupid for asking, etc.?

Comment: I think your question is a good one. It's definitely not a straightforward, obvious solution. The only possible improvement I can see is that you have some shorthand (like "b/c"), but it's perfectly understandable as is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It depends on how far into the game you are. Up until level 24 or so usually you only care about CP and if the CP are similar then the movesets. Once you get into the medium to high 20's that is when things start to get more interesting.

Outside of just movesets and CP there are also IVs (Individual Variables) to keep track of. A Pokemon's IV determines its maximum CP, CP per level, and health. However as long as the IV difference isn't too large, I believe moveset takes priority over IVs because it is more than enough to make up for the CP/HP difference a lot of the times. Another reason why at this point in the game you care a lot more about IVs is because you have a lot more stardust and can finally justify spending them.

Think of good IV pokemon as a long term investment while high CP pokemon as short term. It's really important to balance out the two. And if you follow the moveset chart you are good to go. Keep in mind that movesets are random after evolving so if you find a pre-evolved pokemon you only want to look at CP/IV because IV's are the same after evolution. Weight/size do not matter at all compared to these other statistics.

Best movesets for each pokemon can be found [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1I0Kt_QblThH2rf7vdZOC2L1Nuf7Y1xx68j_KYwfcpXc/htmlview?sle=true#gid=459398309).
IV calculator can be found [here](https://pokeassistant.com/main/ivcalculator).

Answer (score 4):

**Always CP if it is not the final evolution, otherwise abilities unless the CP gap is significant and you don't want to spend stardust to power it up.**

It's [currently unclear](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272621/is-a-pok%C3%A9mons-weight-and-height-relevant) what, if any, influence the weight and size of a Pokemon has on its stats, so I would ignore that for now. If you are going to evolve the Pokemon then its abilities will change, so ignore those if it is not the final evolution. That means that when choosing which Pokemon to keep for evolving, you should only consider their CP.

It is a little more complicated on the final evolution, but it mostly depends on how much stardust and candy you want to spend on powering up. If you want a decent Pokemon to fight with but don't want to spend a lot of stardust and candy to power it up, then keep the highest CP. If you want the absolute best Pokemon, then keep the ones with the best abilities. You can always raise the CP by using stardust and candy, but you can never give a Pokemon better abilities.

Also keep in mind that as you level up, you will naturally run into Pokemon with higher CP, so there is little point in powering up something common like a Pidgy. It may be worth it if you get something rare though, especially if it has really good abilities. It'll depend on how much stardust you have, how long you think you will fight with it, etc.

Answer (score -3):

I don't know if it's fact, but I'm level 26 here and have learned that the more weight and height with higher CP is the way to go. I've experimented a bit with Weedles and Pidgey, and then with other Pokemon it seems to be true.

A XL Weedle around 230 CP evolved to a higher CP than a XS Weedle around a 290 CP.

Try using a CP calculator to see what is the CP range when evolving, an XL will evoke closer to the maximum and a XS will evoke closer to the minimum CP evolution.

Comment: size doesn't matter

Comment: The Big Show won't like to hear that.

Answer (score -4):

CP can still raised up by powering up but weight & height can not , so I think weight & height more important than CP

Comment: Why do you think weight and height are more important than CP? Can you tell us what factors do weight and height have when playing so that we can understand why? Because as far as I know, weight and height do not affect gameplay in any way.